# How do I say "It didn't help that.."

Tags: grammar, vocabulary

In english, we often use the transition "it didn't help that" to indicate that something bad had happened, and that there was another factor that potentially made it even worse.

Ex. He was already very sick from the fever, so it didn't help that he refused to drink soup.

Could I say, 
他已经因为发烧了感到很弱。 更坏他不让别人给他汤喝？

Answer (score 5):

“It didn't help that..” could be translated to "更糟的是" （Literally means worse is）

他已经发烧发到很虚弱了，更糟的是不肯喝汤。

Answer (score 2):

Simply use "还(hai2)".

他已经发烧发到很虚弱了，还不肯喝汤。

Answer (score 2):

Instead of “他已经因为发烧了感到很弱。 **更坏的是**, 他不让别人给他汤喝.” (**what was worse**), you can also translate it literally, such as "他已经因为发烧了感到很弱。 **所以** 不让别人给他汤喝 **并无裨益**/**没有帮助**。（**So**...**didn't help.**)

I personally would put the sentence as “他发烧得很虚弱了, **可还** 拒绝喝汤。(**however yet**)